# Angular Material create a specific $event in a component file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a Chip Component that has an input which fires events for adding chips to a list. I gain access to this element via `@ViewChild("chipInput", { static: true }) chipInput;`

I am attempting to call my `add(event: MatChipInputEvent)` method from another component. Obviously, I need to pass in a valid MatChipInputEvent.

I have tried this:

```
let chips = this.comp.componentInstance.componentRef.instance as ChipInputComponent;

const myEvent: MatChipInputEvent = {
    input: chips.chipInput.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement,
    value: item
};

chips.add(event);
```

This does not appear to work. The `input` property of `myEvent` does not appear to be a valid `HTMLInputElement`. Is there a way to get this `HTMLInputElement` via viewchild from the DOM?

Comment: I wrote an answer, but not sure what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important where the code you mentioned exists.

If it is inside `ngOnInit`, the static should be true.

It it happens after OnInit hook (i.e. in your method), then you should declare `@ViewChild("chipInput", { static: false }) chipInput;`

Read more on this https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

Further, if you want handle chipInput element, you can just write `this.chipInput.*`